# Possibility to filter some spans created by Redis client

Tags: java, redis, spring-data, micrometer-tracing

In my installation, I use Redis sentinel and it floods my spans collector with spans having `db.operation | INFO` like this one:
[image]

I don't really understand why it happening and it is reproducible only in cloud installation, doesn't reproduce locally. But anyways, I think these spans are unwanted.

To eliminate them I tried to create an `ObservationPredicate`, but I cannot use filtration by `context instanceof LettuceObservationContext` since LettuceObservationContext is package private. Therefore I can't really filter some Redis commands to be not submitted as new spans.

I see that there already was [a question like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75875275/lettuce-trace-how-to-ignore-ping-hello-command), but it was deleted for some reason and I can't find an answer.

What is the proper way to eliminate the submission of spans generated by this Redis client that have operations like `info`, `hello`, and `ping`?